# Validation of the input fields

Tags: html

I have two input fields as shown below

```html
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter minimum price">
<input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter maximum price">
<input type="submit">
```

want to validate always first input value must be less than the second input value.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set it manually in html by max = "" min = "" in both field
or You can validate it in your function which is better way to handle it

Comment: what is happening if 1 / 2 and 3 / 4 are valid input values?

Comment: Then have to validate it in the method where pulling the form values